# How do I tell Windsor to add an Interceptor to all components registered that implement IMustBeIntercepted

Tags: castle-windsor

If I registered several components with Windsor.

IAnimal provides BigAnimal
IPerson provides SmellyPerson
IWhale provides BlueWhale

etc.. pretty standard component registeration

all the above types implement IMustBeIntercepted, how do I tell the container add an interceptor to all types that implement IMustBeImplemented so that when Resolve is called it is returned a BigAnimal with an interceptor as defined since it matches. I know I can do this for each one but its extra XML config or programatic config which I want to avoid

Answer (score 5):

Simply create an interface like this:

```
public interface IMustBeIntercepted {}
```

and a facility like this:

```
public class InterceptionFacility : AbstractFacility {
    protected override void Init() {
        Kernel.ComponentRegistered += new Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentDataDelegate(Kernel_ComponentRegistered);
    }

    void Kernel_ComponentRegistered(string key, Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler handler) {
        if(typeof(IMustBeIntercepted).IsAssignableFrom(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation)) {
            handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(TestInterceptor)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the facility to the container using the `<facility>` tag. Now all components that implements `IMustBeIntercepted` will be intercepted by the interceptor `TestInterceptor`.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrote this baby:

```
    public static BasedOnDescriptor WithInterceptor(this BasedOnDescriptor reg, string interceptorComponentName) {
        return reg.Configure(x=> x.Configuration(
                Child.ForName("interceptors").Eq(
                    Child.ForName("interceptor").Eq(
                        "${" + interceptorComponentName + "}"
                ))));
    }
```