# StructureMap Interceptors

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, interceptor

I have a bunch of services that implement various interfaces. eg, `IAlbumService`, `IMediaService` etc.

I want to log calls to each method on these interfaces. How do I do this using StructureMap?

I realise this is pretty much the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420891/how-do-i-tell-windsor-to-add-an-interceptor-to-all-components-registered-that-imp) it is just that I am not using windsor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593914/interception-using-structuremap-3#23598815).

```
static void Main()
{
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.For<Form>().Use<Form1>()
            .InterceptWith(new ActivatorInterceptor<Form1>(y =>  Form1Interceptor(y), "Test"));
    });
    Application.Run(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Form>());

}

public static void Form1Interceptor(Form f)
{
    //Sets the title of the form window to "Testing"
    f.Text = "Testing";
}
```

I wouldn't use ObjectFactory in a real application, but at least the concept is there.

Comment: Nice one! I can't believe you've finally answered my 5yr old question :-) thankfully I haven't been loosing any sleep over this, in fact I can't even remember what it was for!