# Build Expression of Simple Func

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'd like to build Expression for something like this:

```
x => DoSomething(x)
```

Is it possible and how can I accomplish this?

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<string, string>> func = (x) => DoSomething(x);

        Console.WriteLine(func.ToString());
    }

    public static string DoSomething(string s)
    {
        return s; // just as sample
    }
}
```

Here is working fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/j1YKpM
It will be parsed and Lambda will be saved as Expression

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `Func<Tin,Tout>` delegate?

Basically you need a `Func<Tin,Tout>`

```
Func<Tin,Tout> func = x=> DoSomething(x)
```

where `x` is of type `Tin` and `DoSomething` return `Tout` type

Comment: This is not an expression. It will be compiled as anonymous method, not as expression

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question was a bit unclear. This is what I meant:

```
var arg = Expression.Parameter(pluginType, "x");
var method = GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething");
var methodCall = Expression.Call(method, arg);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, methodCall, arg); // I was looking for this
```

Thats what I wanted. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: if you don't need to do it in runtime and you know signature, then you can always use such code `Expression<Action<string>> func = (x) => DoSomething(x);` as it will generate almost the same code as in your answer.

Comment: Yes, this was only a small part of a bigger (already solved) problem. I had to do it all in runtime. Спасибо :)

Comment: If you are interested, here's the complete problem that I was struggling against: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593914/interception-using-structuremap-3/23642317#23642317

Comment: i got it, yeah, then it makes sense. you are welcome :)