# Configure windsor interceptor to hook only marked methods

Tags: configuration, castle-windsor, interceptor

Is there possibility to configure Interceptor to hook methods only of special interface, or by base class?
 Currently I have registered Interceptor that works with scope of connections to one DB. Now I added another scope working with another db and want to add another interceptor, which will hook methods of second scope. It is possible to configure interceptor via xml files, instead of checking target of invocation properties.

I've added interceptor via components:

```
 <component
    type="Common.IoC.SessionScopeInterceptor, Common"
    lifestyle="transient">
 </component>
```

AFAIK this interceptor intercepts all methods of all classes registered in windsor container.

I wand to add something like this^

```
 <component
    type="Common.IoC.SessionScopeInterceptor, Common"
    lifestyle="transient"
    interceptOnlyVirtualMethods="true"
    interceptClass="Common.IoC.SessionScope1, Common"
    >
 </component>
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Could you reword it please?

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic, I populated question body, pls take a look.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420891/how-do-i-tell-windsor-to-add-an-interceptor-to-all-components-registered-that-im?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create your own AbstractFacility that implements your desired behaviour. Essentially, you need to implement something similar to what Mikael Sundberg did in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420891/how-do-i-tell-windsor-to-add-an-interceptor-to-all-components-registered-that-im) question.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's the best I can make in this situation.